# When do ﬂoors and ceilings matter while solving recurrences?

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics, recursive-algorithms

I came across places where floors and ceilings are neglected while solving recurrences.

Example from [CLRS](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0262033844) *(chapter 4, pg.83)* where floor is neglected:

[image]

[Here](http://www.csee.umbc.edu/%7Enam1/TA/HWSols/hw2sol.pdf) (*pg.2, exercise 4.1–1*) is an example where ceiling is ignored:

[image]

In fact in [CLRS](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0262033844) (*pg.88*) its mentioned that:

**"Floors and ceilings usually do not matter when solving recurrences"**

My questions:

1. Here does "usually" means ALL cases ? If yes, i can just forget them all the time.
2. If not, then **when do floors and ceilings really count while solving recurrences** ?

*Note: This ain't a homework problem. I thought about it while I was refreshing my DS and algo concepts.*

Comment: The first example is perfectly valid because $\lfloor n/2 \rfloor \le n/2$. The second example is a little fishy.

Comment: [These notes](http://www.cs.uiuc.edu/~jeffe/teaching/algorithms/notes/99-recurrences.pdf) might help; see especially Section 6.

Comment: @JeffE : thats good stuff.

Comment: In many situations, it is intuitively clear that whether the floor or ceiling function is there or not doesn't make a significant difference compared to the "main" term. Now one could argue, correctly, that if it is intuitively clear, surely a tight proof cannot be hard. True, but if we are solving a hard problem, filling in petty details can distract from the main point.  At the "student" stage, I think one should err in the direction of too much detail.

Comment: The second one is incredibly sloppy. Even with the qualification in the original that the last step holds for $c\ge 1$, it should be $\le$, and the second $\le$ is simply false. I certainly wouldn’t accept it as written.

Comment: "bounding from above" $\neq$ "ignoring. I assume that in the second case, the author implicitly switches from $c$ to some $c' > c$ (which certainly works), as establishing the existence of *some* such constant is likely the goal there. Not saying writing it like this is good (it's *horrible*).